# Is select element appropriate for a nullable property of a model?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

Assume I have a model with a property `WillMarry` of type `bool?` with 3 meanings as follows

- `null` : has not been decided yet.
- `true` : has been decided to marry.
- `false` : has been decided not to marry.

My form uses `select` element as follows

```
<select asp-for="WillMarry">
    <option value="null">Choose an option</option>
    <option value="true">Yes, I will get married</option>
    <option value="false">No, I will not get married</option>
</select>
```

Is it appropriate to use `select` element in this scenario?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your solution is correct, however you have to remove the value null in the first option element, so the code should be like this:

```
<select asp-for="WillMarry">
    <option value="">Choose an option</option>
    <option value="true">Yes, I will get married</option>
    <option value="false">No, I will not get married</option>
</select>
```

Radio button will also work and maybe a little bit user friendly as the user will select the option with one click instead of two as the case in the drop down list

Comment: Why do I need to remove the `null`? I think with explicit `null` is more understandable.

Comment: Because the variable data type is boolean and `null` is not a valid boolean, true,false are valid, an empty string will be a valid null value

Comment: You must use `<option value="">` - If you selected `<option value="null">` then `ModelState` will be invalid because its attempting to bind the text `"null"` to a nullable `bool` which fails

Comment: @StephenMuecke: Thanks. Nice!

Answer (score 1):

You might consider using Radio button here instead of select drop down box
Because, drop down lets the users choose one of the option where as radio button is either true/false.

Comment: But how let the user choose undecided if I use radio button?

Comment: You can provide an option of not decided too with a radio button